# Why doesn't my iOS (Swift) app properly recognize some external display devices?

Tags: ios, swift

So I have an odd issue and my google-fu utterly fails to even provide me the basis of where to start investigating, so even useful keywords to search on may be of use.

I have an iOS application written in swift.  I have a model hooked up to receive notifications about external displays.  On *some* adaptors, I'm able to properly detect and respond to the presence of an external display and programatically switch it out to be something other than a mirror (see code block below).  But with another adaptor, instead of just 'magically' becoming a second screen, I'm asked to 'trust' the external device, and it simply mirrors the device screen.  Not the intended design at all.

```
func addSecondScreen(screen: UIScreen){
    self.externalWindow = UIWindow.init(frame: screen.bounds)
    self.externalWindow!.screen = screen
    self.externalWindow!.rootViewController = self.externalVC
    self.externalWindow!.isHidden = false;
}

@objc func handleScreenDidConnectNotification( _ notification: NSNotification){
    let newScreen = notification.object as! UIScreen
    if(self.externalWindow == nil){
        addSecondScreen(screen: newScreen)
    }
}

@objc func handleScreenDidDisconnectNotification( _ notification: NSNotification){
    if let externalWindow = self.externalWindow{
        externalWindow.isHidden = true
        self.externalWindow = nil
    }
}
```

The worst issue here is that because I'm connecting to an external display to do this, I can't even run this code through the debugger to find out what is going on.  I don't know where to even begin.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Thanks to someone pointing out wifi debugging, I can tell you my notifications are firing off, but they're both firing at the same time, one after the other, when the external adaptor is disconnected.

Comment: You can debug on a real device via WiFi.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, that got me one step forward, two steps back.  Apparently the notifications are getting fired -- both of them on disconnect, when I unplug the device.